# GTK Scrolled Window - scroll to the bottom

Tags: c++, gtk, scrolledwindow

I'm writing an app using GTK+, and I have a problem. I'm using GTK Scrolled Window and I must scroll the vertical scrollbar to the bottom, but I don't know, how. I was looking in Google, but I found nothing.

Comment: what kind of widget do you pack into scrolled window?

Comment: To scrollable window I added a TextView widget.

Comment: you can scroll TextView to the last TextBuffer iter then: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/2.21/classGtk_1_1TextView.html#a9b23b8dbb4362c639abaa05ba9284d3b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must get the adjustment object (hadjustment, vadjustment), and then call methods on them. 
Assuming gtkmm, since you tagged this with c++, something like this:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Adjustment> adj = win->get_vadjustment();
adj->set_value(adj->get_upper());
```

Comment: It does not work - displays the error "'Glib' has not been Declared". I'm not using Glib.

Answer (score 2):

Gtk without Glib would be some feat.  :)

Make sure you can build and run this: [Scrolling Example](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-range-example.html.en)